# Time stamp value getting converted to some other format in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, timestamp, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a CSV file through Apache Spark as below

```
spark.read.format("csv").option("header",true).option("inferSchema",true).load(file_path")
```

There is a timestamp field by the name '**EventTime**' whose value is like `2012-11-12T01:01:00Z`

But on showing the field from `dataframe`, it's value is getting converted into `2012-11-12 06:31:00`. I think `GMT + 5:30` is getting applied to it's value. I can see it for all the values of this column. I am not actually sure what's the reason for it.

I don't want date time value getting converted. How can I resolve this?

Comment: try using org.apache.spark.functions.date_format

Comment: @AssafMendelson But how can we do -5:30 to the date time as it's already been converted.

Comment: I believe that this is a representation issue, i.e. it is showing you the time in the local machine's time. If you set the timezone as part of the format, it should print it ok. You can make sure by converting the time column to long (cast as long) and checking the actual time